# Quantum Mechanics: Rotation operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, operators, hilbert-space

How do I know what direction of the rotation operator to use on the initial state of a spin-1/2 particle?

For example, a spin-1/2 particle initially in the $\lvert y \rangle$ state enters a SGz device. What rotation operator do I use to find the final state of the particle?

Answer (score 1):

When you make a measurement it is useful to change from whatever basis you were working in before to the new basis spanned by the eigenvectors of the observable. In the case of a Stern-Gerlach apparatus, this will more vividly explain why the experiment does not actually rotate anything.

If we have $|+;y\rangle= (1,0)$, then in the $S_{z}$ basis this would be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|+;z\rangle - i|-;z\rangle)$. When you make a measurement in the z-basis, then, you are 'selecting' one of those two eigenstates rather than rotating the y-basis spin.

This is somewhat unintuitive, because if you just measured it along the y-direction then it is natural to think that the measurement in the z-direction has changed it. However, putting the y-state in the z-basis illustrates that in some sense it was *always in the z-direction anyway.*

Answer (score 0):

a Stern Garlach apparatus does not rotate the state of the particle, what it does is to split a beam or, if you have a single particle, it ``chooses" a state in the desired direction. What you might be looking for is how to write the eigenstate in terms of Z basis. For a 1/2 spin it is going to be:

$$|\pm \rangle_y  = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( |+\rangle_z  \pm \ i\  |-\rangle_z\right) $$

both outcomes are equally likely.

For larger spins, you will have to use Wigner D matrix to find the coefficient of the superposing states.

is this what you are asking?

Comment: Sweet, makes sense. So what does the rotation operator do on a particle and is there a device that rotates it in such a way? What is the purpose of rotation operator?

Comment: There are many uses I know of, and infinitely many more that I don't know... You can use it to generate the state I have written there in my answer, by rotating the y+ state  by -Pi, or you could use it to find the expectation value in terms of angular orientation etc.

Comment: Pardon my questions; I'm still learning this stuff. What is the operator you used to determine that state?

Comment: The generator of rotation is angular momentum (just as the generator of time evolution is the Hamiltonian). The rotation operator is just: exp(-i jx theta/hbar), in this case theta is 90 degree in the negative direction (going from +y to +z).